# Preventing a single query from appearing in slow query log

Tags: mysql, performance, logging

Is a way to prevent a single query from appearing in mysql slow query log?

One may actually disable logging before executing the query (by setting a global variable) and enable it back after the query, but this would prevent logging in other threads as well, which is not desirable.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why? Getting constantly reminded about this is a good thing. The way to fix it would be to make the query run faster. :-)  PS: If the query is only moderately slow, you could adjust the definition of "slow" to just exclude it.

Comment: The answer to "Why?" is that there are queries that are destined to be slow and are ok, since they are performed by a robot late at night :-) And there are other queries performed by a PHP frontend, which _are_ important.

Comment: Yes, but is it a problem that they appear in the log? You can just ignore them. Fiddling with the "slow query" feature to make it suppress some things could make it suppress too much.

Comment: That's not so much of a problem - thanks to mysqldumpslow - but if it can still be done better, why not do it? :-)

Comment: "if it can still be done better, why not do it?" That is the part we disagree. I'd say you'd make things worse by suppressing the warning you don't want to see. This is collecting valuable operational data. Even if there is no problem, wouldn't it be nice to see how much slower the batch query gets as data volume grows, or to detect unusual spikes and things like that?

Comment: Perhaps you're right. However, if the initial question could be answered I'd like to see the answer.

Comment: It's very reasonable to suppress expected long maintenance queries from appearing in the slow query log, so that actual problematic slow queries are more visible.  More generally speaking, it's rarely to never a good idea to have a warning that you simply ignore because you know it's ok; once a warning is understood not to be a problem, the necessary changes should be made to prevent it continuing to appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MySQL 5.1 and later, you can make runtime changes to the time threshold for which queries are logged in the slow query log.  Set it to something ridiculously high and the query is not likely to be logged.

```
SET SESSION long_query_time = 20000;
SELECT ...whatever...
SET SESSION long_query_time = 2;
```

Assuming 2 is the normal threshold you use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can prevet a single query from appearing in the slow query log, but you could use a grepped output from the query log. Having said that, if I remember correctly, every slow query is dumped as multiple lines so it would not be easy to grep it out, but not impossible.

*mysqldumpslow* has a "-g pattern" option to "Consider only queries that match the (grep-style) pattern." which may help in your situation.

I hope this helps.

Cheers
Tymek